# C# Delete everything after a character but before another

Tags: c#, string

Im working with a piece of dynamic data I need to remove some but not the final part of the string.

```
var x = "<abc><static string data> Data inside here is dynamic </abc>"
```

I want to be able to delete everything after string data, but keep the closing brackets of `</abc>`.

I can delete everything by doing;

```
x = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("<static string data>") + 1);
```

but that removes the `</abc>` part and I dont want to manually add `</abc>` back in as it defeats the point of what im trying to achieve.

Comment: How about `Regex.Replace(x, "(?<=<static string data>).*(?=</abc>)", "")`? Does that do what you want?

Comment: Does it always start & end with `<abc>` + `</abc>`, or is that also dynamic, e.g. can they be different tags?

Comment: Just find the index of the closing part (depending on your needs, maybe with `</`), and append that part?
somthing like `x = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("<static string data>") + 1) + x.Substring(x.IndexOf("</"));`

Comment: Looks like *invalid* xml to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done more gracefully, but for demonstration:

```
    var x = "<abc><static string data> Data inside here is dynamic </abc>";
    var start = x.IndexOf("<static string data>") + ("<static string data>").Length;
    var end = x.IndexOf("</abc>");

    var newStr = x.Substring(0, start) + x.Substring(end);
    Console.Writeline(newStr);
```

Output:

```
<abc><static string data></abc>
```

Comment: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZN41TQ) helps to validate written in head code ;)